# Why pull-backs are homomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm studying Fulton's [book](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MA_Algebra/MAg_Algebraic%20geometry/Fulton%20W.%20Algebraic%20curves%20%28free%20web%20version,%20AW,%202008%29%28129s%29_MAg_.pdf) and I didn't understand why this is an homomorphism:

[image]

I'm sure this is a silly question, maybe I'm forgetting something, because I can't understand why this is an homomorphism since $f$ and $\varphi$ are not necessarily homomorphism.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $f$ and $\phi$ are not homomorphisms. But so what? You can check by hand that $\tilde{\phi}$ is a homomorphism, because the ring operations are pointwise.

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, yes, of course. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$((f_1 + f_2) \circ \phi)(x) = (f_1 + f_2)(\phi(x)) = f_1(\phi(x)) + f_2(\phi(x)) = (f_1 
\circ \phi)(x) + (f_2 \circ \phi)(x)$$
and similarly for multiplication (the operation is irrelevant for this calculation, it could be any binary operation on $k$ extended in the natural way to functions into $k$).

Comment: of course, thank you!